# Yii: use Chtml:link without change browser URL

Tags: hyperlink, yii, url-routing

I have "delete" links on my page (just next to the name of each user) which redirect to an "deleteUser" action.

All work fine but when I click on the link then the URL change in my browser.

befor delete:

```
 http://localhost/forsys/person/
```

and after:

```
 http://localhost/forsys/person/deletePerson/20
```

and it's quite annoying.

I tried several different ways like redirect and forward on my index action or things like that but nothing I did worked fine :/

So if you have an idea to solve this issue you are welcome :)

Here is my link:

> echo CHtml::link('delete',"#", array('submit' =>
>   array('deletePerson','id'=>$people['person']->id)));

Comment: You want to go to the page http://localhost/forsys/person/deletePerson/20, right? But you want to be redirected afterwards? Can you show the code for your `actionDeleteUser` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried on your delete action:

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
```

or

```
$this->redirect(Yii::app()->request->urlReferrer);
```